# Qt SDK version 1.0 & version 1.1

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, ovi

I am developing an application for Nokia Symbian since last two months, Nokia is a new platform for me I have good experience in iPhone development, I started Qt SDK 1.0 what I found 1.0 was not really good for some mobile device specially in UI, I just moved out to Qt SDK 1.1 released on 1st March 2011 I went through QML (Qt Quick) I found it really good in UI experience, finally when I reach to OVi for publishing my application OVi just refused my application due to Qt SDK 1.1 which is not supported on Nokia Symbian devices yet.

Again I cam back to Qt SDK 1.0 I used QDelearativeView and used same QML structure its working fine on simulator but when I am trying to build it for Symbian device I am getting error "no such file or directory".

Now I have number of questions listed below

1 - How can I fix this error and publish it to OVi
2 - Any good resource for publishing & signed process for Symbian devices
3 - Any expectation how much long Ovi would take to support Qt SDK 1.1

Thanks in advance,
Mohammad Asif

Comment: @icktoofay He's using QtSDK 1.1 which contains Qt 4.7.2 and QtCreator 2.1.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your error?

Answer (score 1):

Qt SDK 1.0 contains Qt 4.6.3 which doesn't support QtDeclarative. SDK 1.1 Beta contains Qt 4.7.2. That's the reason for compilation error.

According to [this](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?221525-Publish-Qt-4.7.2-application), you could build your app on SDK 1.1 Beta, package it with the currently available Qt Smart Installer and submit it. Though it will only be deployed to store once Qt 4.7 based Smart Installer is available.

For Ovi Store related questions I suggest you consult [Forum Nokia's Publishing to Ovi Store forum](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?202-Publishing-to-Ovi-Store).